# How to connect mysql with java for html forms?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have html forms for login. I want to connect those forms to MySQL using Java through JDBC connections but when I execute the java file it shows the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java: 200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.j ava:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:3 06)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launche r.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:2 51)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoade r.java:319)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at MissingRuzdi.MissingDbConnection.SqlConnection(Mis singDbConnection.java:28)
    at MissingRuzdi.MissingDbConnection.main(MissingDbCon nection.java:55)
```

I have set the classpath of connectorJ.

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Comment: To do this, you have to use mysql-connector jar file,

Answer (score 0):

hi Avnish check this coding

```
import java.sql.*;

public class getmySQLConnection 
{
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
                DB db = new DB();
                Connection conn=db.dbConnect(
                  "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
        }

}

class DB
{
        public DB() {}

        public Connection dbConnect(String db_connect_string,
          String db_userid, String db_password)
        {
                try
                {
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                          db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);

                        System.out.println("connected");
                        return conn;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                }
        }
};
```

Comment: when i wrote the above code and compiled it gave me following error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MySQLTest (wrong name: test/MySQLTest)

Comment: Check Your localhostname and username and Password and Table NAme

Comment: i knoiw myusername and password. how to check localhost name

Comment: my table name is 'users' and databasename is 'ticketing'

Comment: localhost:3306/test--->replace test to Your task name,,, if u run in website means check the Bar,,, that is the Address

Comment: it will works fine for me..

Comment: hey see i have a web application for which i want to use this db ok ! where in i hv used html css javascript , but i am not using any tools for that and also i want to connect it to sql using java i.e. jdbc. so i want to ask is this the correct way or is there anyother way .

Comment: now i changed that coding check and try

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/MysqlConnect.shtml

Comment: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/11/24/jdbc-mysql-database-connection-example/

Comment: Check this All links

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all